# Create blank UL list for Blade templating system - Laravel + jQuery TagIt

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

trying to use jQuery tagit with laravel and blade.

It works fine, but the rest of the form is using blade and I want to keep it all the same so wish to use blade to create the list. However, I cant seem to find a way to create a blank ul list using blade.

So the blade for ul looks like:

```
{{ HTML::ul(array('a', 'b'), array('class' => 'mylist')) }}
```

Which works. But I am not pre-populating my tagit ul so using this currently:

```
<ul id="myTags" name="tags" class="form-control form-control-ultagit">
</ul>
```

I normally wouldnt mind too much, but wishing to use the Input::old() method.

Any help? When using:

```
{{ HTML::ul(array(), array('class' => 'mylist')) }}
```

Nothing is displayed and the UL is not created.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to render an empty list using HTML:ul() or Html::ol()